# How to find the transaction is settled/Unsettled in Authorize.net?

Tags: php, authorize.net

How Can I find whether the transaction made by user is settled or Unsettled in the authorize.net.I am using AIM.
I want to get through coding.When the transaction is completed and I cant find transaction status.But I want to get whether it goes for settled or unsettled transaction.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Eh, it's been a while since I manually implemented credit card processing through Authorize.net, but I don't recall any type of settled/unsettled property. You usually send a request to the gateway to process a payment (with all the CC info), and then it returns a status code that tells you if the payment went through or failed. Since it's a credit card, not a tab, the funds are transferred from the buyer's account to yours pretty much instantaneously.

Comment: Correction, in addition to pass/fail/error, there is a 4th response code, but that should never come up in a standard setup. It happens when you accept partial payments or if you've set up your account so that you have to review and approve each transaction manually. See the subsection in Section 4 entitled "Response Reason Codes...":

http://developer.authorize.net/guides/AIM/

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses...I will go through it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot get this information through coding as no API Authorize.Net offers allows for this. It can only be done through the control panel. When you process a transaction and it is approved you can assume the transaction is unsettled. Transactions are settled once per day usually around midnight Pacific Time. After that you can assume a transaction is settled.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that. What exactly does it mean when a transaction is "unsettled"? Have the funds not been deducted from the purchaser yet? Or does it just mean the funds are in between the purchaser's account and the merchant's account (e.g. being held by Authorize.net)?

Comment: To make the process of handling transaction easier for everyone involved (merchant, acquirer, processing bank) transactions are processed in batches once per day. An unsettled transaction has the funds held on a cardholder's credit card for the merchant purchased from. Once that transaction is settled the funds are taken from the cardholder and transferred to the merchant. As soon as an approval code is given for a transaction, as far as the merchant is concerned, the transaction is complete and they can count on receiving that money within 2-3 business days depending on the kind of card.

Comment: Thanks John conde. My doubt is  after 12 hours if it is unsettled transaction (ie if it is failed for validation when the bank people go through it(I dont know whether this situation will arise or not)) is there any posibilities to inform the merchant to make the refund(unheld) the amound for the user.

Comment: Unsettled means it is just not submitted for payment to you. Once the approval is given it can't fail validation or anything because no more validation is done.

Comment: This isn't correct (at least not anymore). http://developer.authorize.net/api/transaction_details/ lets you view transaction details, including if its been settled.

Answer (score 6):

As of 03-16-2011 authorize.net has released two new calls to the Transaction Details API, getUnsettledTransactionList and getBatchStatistics.

getUnsettledTransactionList returns up to 1,000 unsettled transactions per call, returning the most recent transactions. The information returned in the response will be the same as what's returned in getTransactionList call.

getBatchStatistics returns the batch stats for a single batch like settlement state and time, charge count, decline count, etc.

For more info, check out the XML guide and the SOAP guide.

At the time of writing the PHP SDK is at version 1.1.6 and does not have this function built into the TD api, however if you look at the documentation provided above, as well as [this example page](https://apitest.authorize.net/soap/v1/service.asmx?op=GetUnsettledTransactionList), you will see that getting a list of unsettled transactions is in fact possible.

[from this page](http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/News-and-Announcements/Introducing-getUnsettledTransactionList-and-getBatchStatistics/td-p/11184)

Answer (score 2):

I've followed this link http://developer.authorize.net/api/transaction_details/ and get this code from there,

```
<?php
require_once "anet_php_sdk/AuthorizeNet.php";
define("AUTHORIZENET_API_LOGIN_ID", "YOURLOGIN");
define("AUTHORIZENET_TRANSACTION_KEY", "YOURKEY");

// Get Settled Batch List
$request = new AuthorizeNetTD;
$response = $request->getSettledBatchList();
echo count($response->xml->batchList->batch) . " batches\n";
foreach ($response->xml->batchList->batch as $batch) {
    echo "Batch ID: " . $batch->batchId . "\n";
}

// Get Transaction Details
$transactionId = "12345";
$response = $request->getTransactionDetails($transactionId);
echo $response->xml->transaction->transactionStatus;
```

but I m getting this error message.

User authentication failed due to invalid authentication values.

Comment: Hello Musaddiq, I know this is an old post, but maybe you know the answer. Is there a way to bring a list of settled transactions without having to call the batchList first and getTransactionDetails later? Its getting hard to confirm the settlement of above 1K transactions daily. Thanks.

Comment: Hello Danielle, sorry it was my client account and I was able to test things at that time. Right now I'm not having any active account to test.

Comment: Thanks Musaddiq! It turns out Authorize does not have the option to bring all settled accounts. You can get the batchIds, and then the settled accounts on that batch. I can't believe they dont have a simple option like that. Thanks so much for your answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in @cwd's answer, the most reliable way to know if a transaction is settled is to call `getUnsettledTransactionList` or `getBatchStatistics`, but you can also just check what your **Transaction Cut-off Time** is set to.

Log in to your Authorize.net admin, click Account > Transaction Cut-Off Time

My account is set to **4:00 PM PDT** so you can just compare your transaction time to the cut off time. Something like:

```
$createdTime = new DateTime($charge['createdTime']);

// starting point for settle time
$settleTime = new DateTime($createdTime->format('Y-m-d') . ' 16:00:00');
$now = new DateTime();

// if card was charged after settle time for 
// that day, move settle time to the next day
if ($createdTime > $settleTime) {
    $settleTime->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
}

if ($now > $settleTime) $settled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.authorize.net/api/transaction_details/ is the API you are looking for.