# Error : element in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd' has incomplete content

Tags: authorize.net

I've the exact query which is being ask here: [How to find the transaction is settled/Unsettled in Authorize.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185304/how-to-find-the-transaction-is-settled-unsettled-in-authorize-net). I am using anet-java-sdk (1.8.4) from the http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.authorize/anet-java-sdk.
I am looking to get the list of settled and Unsettled Transaction. But when I run the following code I see error coming:

```
public static final String apiLoginID = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
    public static final String transactionKey = "yyyyyyyyyyyyyxxx";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Merchant merchant = Merchant.createMerchant(Environment.SANDBOX, apiLoginID, transactionKey);
        Transaction transaction = merchant.createReportingTransaction(TransactionType.GET_TRANSACTION_DETAILS);
        ReportingDetails details = ReportingDetails.createReportingDetails();
        details.setBatchIncludeStatistics(true);
        transaction.setReportingDetails(details);

        Result<Transaction> result = (Result<Transaction>) merchant.postTransaction(transaction);
        System.out.println("Code : "+result.getMessages().get(0).getCode());
        System.out.println("Text : "+result.getMessages().get(0).getText());

        for (BatchDetails batchDetail : result.getReportingDetails().getBatchDetailsList()) {
            System.out.println("---------------------");
            System.out.println("ID : "+ batchDetail.getBatchId() );
            System.out.println("Settlement State : "+ batchDetail.getSettlementState().value());
            System.out.println("local settlementTime: "+ batchDetail.getSettlementTimeLocal().toString());
        }
    }
```

The error coming are as follows:
07/11/15 02:22:16,984:  INFO [main] (net.authorize.util.LogHelper:24) - Use **Proxy: 'false'**

```
Code : E00003
Text : The element 'getTransactionDetailsRequest' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd' has incomplete content. List of possible elements expected: 'refId, transId' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd'.
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making a incorrect request to the Authorize.Net APIs,
If you want to get list of settled transactions
use : `getSettledBatchListRequest`

if you want to get list of unsettled transactions
use : `getUnsettledTransactionListRequest`

Instead I see you are using `getTransactionDetailsRequest` which gives details of a single transaction, an thus it require a transactionID, which is the error you are getting.

For more understanding of these type of APIs refer : [Authorize.Net Reference](http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#transaction-reporting)

also, here are java sample codes for [getUnsettledTransactionList](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sample-code-java/blob/master/src%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fnet%2Fauthorize%2Fsample%2FTransactionReporting%2FGetUnsettledTransactionList.java)